# Dropdowns option text to be shown in a textbox but not to replace existing text

Tags: javascript

```
function showit(sel) {
  var i = sel.selectedIndex;
  if (i != -1) {
    document.getElementById("title").value = sel.options[i].text;
  }
}
```

I use this function in 4 dropdowns and works to show the option text instead of the value. The problem is that when a dropdown changes it replace the value of the textbox.

My question is how to change the code so that the `title textbox` to show all the info from the selectede dropdowns and not replacing them ?

Comment: `+=` would do the trick.

Comment: Do you mean that you want up to 4 values, one from each of the dropdowns? So that you only have at most 4 items combined in to one textbox, but so that they update their own section of the text if they are then changed again afterwards?

Comment: @Klors I first used the answer below, and you are right, if the dropdown is changed, then the textbox adds it too. If there is a solution of replacing their own section it would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function showit(sel) {
  var i = sel.selectedIndex;
  if (i != -1) {
    document.getElementById("title").value += sel.options[i].text+'\n';
  }
}
```

Comment: the '\n' makes a new line with every iteration